# generate visual party effect inside activity body

Tags: android, visual-effects

Please help me, how I could to generate the party special effect, like the below image.
This effect is similar to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.popularapp.sevenmins app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnvMK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Konfetti particle system](https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti)